# Remap "Show the Overview" to control in Gnome ( Fedora 20 )

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to remap "Show the Overview" to control, but the gui will not allow it. Is there a config file somewhere I can use to specify this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAfLu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install 'dconf-editor' if you don't have.
Launch it and go in left panel to org->gnome->mutter. There you can change value of 'overlay-key' to 'Control_L' or 'Control_R' or any other key if you want.
Setting is applied instantly after closing edition (click some where else in dconf-editor).